# Make user join discord guild with guilds.join request

Tags: discord, discord.js

**Code:**

```js
let response = await fetch(
    `https://discord.com/api/guilds/877414872068001853/members/[user id]`,
    {
        method: 'PUT',
        access_token: `Bearer [user access code]`,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bot [bot token]`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }
);
console.log(response);
```

- The bot is in the server that I want the user to join
- The `guilds.join` oauth scope is set

**Error**:

```js
Response {
    size: 0,
    timeout: 0,
    [Symbol(Body internals)]: { body: [PassThrough], disturbed: false, error: null },
    [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
      url: 'https://discord.com/api/guilds/877414872068001853/members/522503261941661727',
      status: 400,
      statusText: 'Bad Request',
      headers: [Headers],
      counter: 0
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to supply `access_token` in the body for this endpoint, yet you didn't place access_token in the request body. [This might help.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user15517071

I had the access_token not in the body, and also the "access token" i was using was just the redirect token from discord oauth so i needed to use the actual access Token discord provides you after getting the users details, and it works.

```js
{
 method: 'PUT',
 body: JSON.stringify({
   access_token: `Bearer User_AccessToken`,
 }),
 headers: {
  "Authorization": `Bot Bot_Token`,
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
 }
};
```

Comment: So you can potentially make someone join using this?